# Detecting network is down from browser Fetch API

Tags: javascript, browser, fetch-api

I made the below utility to handle the web requests for me:

```
import configureStore from '../configureStore';
import { logout } from '../containers/App/actions';

const store = configureStore({});

/**
 * Parses the JSON returned by a network request
 *
 * @param  {object} response A response from a network request
 *
 * @return {object}          The parsed JSON from the request
 */
function parseJSON(response) {
  if (
    response.status === 204 ||
    response.status === 205 ||
    parseInt(response.headers.get('content-length')) === 0
  ) {
    return null;
  }
  return response.json();
}

/**
 * Checks if a network request came back fine, and throws an error if not
 *
 * @param  {object} response   A response from a network request
 *
 * @return {object|undefined} Returns either the response, or throws an error
 */
function checkStatus(response) {
  if (response.status >= 200 && response.status < 300) {
    return response;
  }

  const error = new Error(response.statusText);
  error.response = response;
  throw error;
}

/**
 * Requests a URL, returning a promise
 *
 * @param  {string} url       The URL we want to request
 * @param  {object} [options] The options we want to pass to "fetch"
 *
 * @return {object}           The response data
 */
export default function request(url, options) {
  const headers = {
    Accept: 'application/json',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'Access-Control-Request-Headers': 'Content-Type, Authorization'
  };
  const token = localStorage.getItem('token');
  if (token) {
    headers['Authorization'] = `Bearer ${token}`;
  }
  const newOptions = {
    ...options,
    mode: 'cors',
    headers
  };
  // FIXME
  // properly handle `net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED`
  // currently, we return `cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'status')`
  return fetch(url, newOptions)
    .then(checkStatus)
    .then(parseJSON)
    .catch(err => {
      // check for 401 here and throw an action to clean the store and the logout.
      if (err.response.status === 401) {
        store.dispatch(logout);
      }
      throw err;
    });
}
```

This is working except when a network error happens. Since fetch does not throw on errors, I need to handle this case myself.

Only, it is NOT working. I tried adding `if (!response.ok)` to the `checkStatus`. It is however also not working, since the browser throws a CORS error.

How do I handle this, so my `request()` throws `Failed to fetch` instead of `cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'status')`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ended-up with:

```
async function parseJSON(response) {
  if (
    response.status === 204 ||
    response.status === 205 ||
    parseInt(response.headers.get('content-length')) === 0
  ) {
    return null;
  }
  return await response.json();
}

function checkStatus(response) {
  if (response.status >= 200 && response.status < 300) {
    return response;
  }    
  const error = new Error(response.statusText);
  error.response = response;
  throw error;
}

export default async function request(url, options) {
  const headers = {
    Accept: 'application/json',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'Access-Control-Request-Headers': 'Content-Type, Authorization'
  };
  const token = localStorage.getItem('token');
  if (token) {
    headers['Authorization'] = `Bearer ${token}`;
  }
  const newOptions = {
    ...options,
    mode: 'cors',
    headers
  };
  try {
    const result = await fetch(url, newOptions);
    return await parseJSON(checkStatus(result));
  } catch (err) {
    // check for 401 here and throw an action to clean the store and the logout.
    if (err != null && 'response' in err && err.response.status === 401) {
      store.dispatch(logout);
    }
    throw err;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

> Since fetch does not throw on error

Fetch does throw on error:

> A fetch() promise only rejects when a network error is encountered
> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/fetch

It won't tell you specifically that the network is down, but it will throw an error.

Your error is likely occurring here:

```
if (err.response.status === 401) {
```

That's because fetch is throwing an actual `Error` instance when the network is down, thus response is `null`, so you can't access `status` on `null`. So if `response` doesn't exist on `err`, just throw it:

```js
return fetch(url, newOptions)
  .then(checkStatus)
  .then(parseJSON)
  .catch(err => {
    // check for 401 here and throw an action to clean the store and the logout.
    if (err != null && 'response' in err && err.response.status === 401) {
      store.dispatch(logout);
    }
    throw err;
  });
```

Comment: nope, this is not the problem. catch receives `err` as: `TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'status')`

Comment: @IgorShmukler Fetch won't return undefined, ever. Remove all your then().then().catch() and just have `then((v) => console.log({v}), (e) => console.log({e}))` and see what you get in your console after running it.

Answer (score 1):

`fetch()` *does* throw on network errors. The only error it doesn't throw is HTTP errors.

Comment: how do i fix/rewrite my promise chain then so that `catch` receives the actual error that was thrown by `fetch`?

Comment: Looks like you already are catching errors. Are you certain the error doesn't show up in your catch clause? To make things simpler, consider switching to async/await